# Highchart - Preprocess data using json

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

I am trying to generate a simple bar chart with the json data. Here is what I have tried without using the json data ([`http://jsfiddle.net/6hkcn4qf/2/`](http://jsfiddle.net/6hkcn4qf/2/)).

I need to use this mock json [`https://mocki.io/v1/af3abd57-1c07-4df0-b591-4d17796e2c29`](https://mocki.io/v1/af3abd57-1c07-4df0-b591-4d17796e2c29) to generate the same bar. Here is the fiddle I am trying to achieve [`http://jsfiddle.net/6hkcn4qf/3/`](http://jsfiddle.net/6hkcn4qf/3/). It is not generating the chart based on the highchart documentation.

Can someone guide me on how to achieve this?

Also, how to change the bar colors dynamically based on the fruit name in this?

Thanks

Comment: You've bypassed site requirements that you show code by formatting your links as code. Don't do that. Please see [ask] and revise your post to add enough information _here_ for us to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to preprocess your data and adapt it to the format required by Highcharts. For example:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://mocki.io/v1/af3abd57-1c07-4df0-b591-4d17796e2c29',
    success: function(data) {
      const processedData = [];

      for (let key in data) {
        processedData.push({
          name: key,
          y: data[key]
        });
      }

      options.series[0].data = processedData;
      Highcharts.chart('container', options);
    }
  });
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wm2pzrxj/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.data

Comment: Thanks for the great help in providing the solution. The bar color is not changing. Do I need to append the color in the processData ?

Comment: Hi @Geek, I am glad that I could help. As to your question - yes, you can define a color for an individual point in `processedData`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wcagufkz/